# How to use max function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max, squeryl

I am trying to write a query to find the top sales person in the shop and trying to Display the employee name, the shop where he/she is employed and the value of sales. I only want to output the employee with highest number of sales at the moment, my query outputs all the employees with their figures.

```
SELECT empnin, shopname, SUM( Rentalrate ) AS Sales
FROM frs_FilmRental
NATURAL JOIN frs_Shop
GROUP BY empnin
```

This is the following results I get with my query:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the top sales person per shop, then you need to filter.  This is best done in the `WHERE` clause.

In MySQL, this type of query is actually most easily accomplished using variables:

```
select fs.*
from (select fs.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = shopname, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := shopname, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select fr.empnin, s.shopname, SUM(fr.Rentalrate) AS Sales
            from frs_FilmRental fr join
                 frs_Shop s
                 using (??)  -- add the appropriate column here
            group by empnin
           ) fs cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @s := '') params
      order by shopname, sales desc
     ) fs
where rn = 1;
```

Also, don't use `natural join`.  It is a bug waiting to happen, because it hides the keys used for joining and some unexpected columns might end up being used.

Answer (score 0):

Here, like this:

```
SELECT top 10 empnin, min(shopname) as Shopname, SUM( Rentalrate ) AS Sales
FROM frs_FilmRental
NATURAL JOIN frs_Shop
GROUP BY empnin
order by sum(Rentalrate) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 empnin, shopname, SUM( Rentalrate ) AS Sales
FROM frs_FilmRental
NATURAL JOIN frs_Shop
GROUP BY empnin ORDER BY Sales
```

Try the above for sql server